# I can make an div fade in onclick, but how do i make it fade out?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was working on making this TOS page but ran into a problem with the fade-in/fade-out animations.

I got the div to fade in when the button is clicked but don't know how to let it fade-out when the button is clicked again. Any tips would be helpful

https://jsfiddle.net/MakkerHeineken/khs8b43f/1/

```js
function unhideTOS() {
  document.getElementById("text").style.display = "";
}

function unlockBTN() {
  document.getElementById("text").style.display = "";
}

function scrollToAccept() {
  const terms = document.querySelector('.terms-and-conditions');
  const button = document.querySelector('.accept');
  // const watch = document.querySelector('.watch');

  if (!terms) {
    return; // quit function because there is no terms
  }

  // fires on page load because can't find element
  function obCallback(payload) {
    // console.log(payload[0].isIntersecting); // whether element is in view or not
    // console.log(payload[0].intersectionRatio); // how much of the element is showing
    if (payload[0].intersectionRatio === 1) {
      button.disabled = false;
      // stop observing the last element
      ob.unobserve(terms.lastElementChild);
    }
  }

  // takes in callback parameter
  // will be called every time it needs to check if something is currently on the page
  // watcher (needs to be told what to watch
  const ob = new IntersectionObserver(obCallback, {
    root: terms,
    threshold: 1,
  });

  // call observe method on what we want to watch
  // ob.observe(watch);
  ob.observe(terms.lastElementChild);

}
scrollToAccept();

$('.yes').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.TOSHIDE').toggleClass('active');
  //$(this).parents('ul').next().toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.wrapper-all {
  min-height: 94vh;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 80vh;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

button {
  background: #133C55;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

button[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.1;
  /* transform: translateX(-300%) scale(0.5); */
}

.terms-and-conditions {
  overflow: scroll;
}

footer {
  background-color: #192718;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

footer .container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

footer .container a {
  color: #fff;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #fce26a;
}

.tacbox {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 2em;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #eee;
  max-width: 800px;
}

input {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.TOSHIDE {
  display: none;
}

.TOSHIDE.active {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-in-image {
  animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn 5s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fade-out {
  animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tacbox">
    <!-- The code for the checkbox + download if checked. -->
    I agree to these &zwnj;<a href="#tos" class="yes">Terms and Conditions.</a>
    <br>
    <a id="text" style="display:none" href="file.doc" Download>Download!</a>
  </div>

  <div class="TOSHIDE fade-in-image">
    <div class="wrapper-all">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="terms-and-conditions">
          <h1>Terms and Conditions</h1>
          <p>Disclaimer THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF MERCHANTABILITY OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. You are the Current Maintainer of the Software, and to permit recipients of the Licensed Product for any such warranty, support,
            indemnity or liability obligations to one or more recipients of Covered Code. However, You may do so in a commercial product offering.</p>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <button class="accept" disabled autocomplete="off" id="myCheck" onclick="unlockBTN()">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: FYI, jQuery 1.7 was released in **2011**. You might consider upgrading.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You've included much more code here than is necessary to show your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier approach using jQuery animation, no CSS animation

```js
function scrollToAccept() {
  const terms = document.querySelector('.terms-and-conditions');
  const button = document.querySelector('.accept');
  // const watch = document.querySelector('.watch');

  if (!terms) {
    return; // quit function because there is no terms
  }

  // fires on page load because can't find element
  function obCallback(payload) {
    // console.log(payload[0].isIntersecting); // whether element is in view or not
    // console.log(payload[0].intersectionRatio); // how much of the element is showing
    if (payload[0].intersectionRatio === 1) {
      button.disabled = false;
      // stop observing the last element
      ob.unobserve(terms.lastElementChild);
    }
  }

  // takes in callback parameter
  // will be called every time it needs to check if something is currently on the page
  // watcher (needs to be told what to watch
  const ob = new IntersectionObserver(obCallback, {
    root: terms,
    threshold: 1,
  });

  // call observe method on what we want to watch
  // ob.observe(watch);
  ob.observe(terms.lastElementChild);

}
scrollToAccept();

$('.yes').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.TOSHIDE').fadeToggle(3000).toggleClass('active');
  //$(this).parents('ul').next().toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.wrapper-all {
  min-height: 94vh;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 80vh;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

button {
  background: #133C55;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

button[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.1;
  /* transform: translateX(-300%) scale(0.5); */
}

.terms-and-conditions {
  overflow: scroll;
}

footer {
  background-color: #192718;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

footer .container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

footer .container a {
  color: #fff;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #fce26a;
}

.tacbox {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 2em;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #eee;
  max-width: 800px;
}

input {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.TOSHIDE {
  display: none;
}

.TOSHIDE.active {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Terms of Service</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./scroll-to-accept.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    function unhideTOS() {
      document.getElementById("text").style.display = "";
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function unlockBTN() {
      document.getElementById("text").style.display = "";
    }
  </script>

  <div class="tacbox">
    <!-- The code for the checkbox + download if checked. -->
    I agree to these &zwnj;<a href="#tos" class="yes">Terms and Conditions.</a>
    <br>
    <a id="text" style="display:none" href="file.doc" Download>Download!</a>
  </div>

  <div class="TOSHIDE">
    <div class="wrapper-all">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="terms-and-conditions">
          <h1>Terms and Conditions</h1>
          <p>Disclaimer THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF MERCHANTABILITY OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. You are the Current Maintainer of the Software, and to permit recipients of the Licensed Product for any such warranty, support,
            indemnity or liability obligations to one or more recipients of Covered Code. However, You may do so in a commercial product offering.</p>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <button class="accept" disabled autocomplete="off" id="myCheck" onclick="unlockBTN()">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./scroll-to-accept.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

with CSS animation

```js
function scrollToAccept() {
  const terms = document.querySelector('.terms-and-conditions');
  const button = document.querySelector('.accept');
  // const watch = document.querySelector('.watch');

  if (!terms) {
    return; // quit function because there is no terms
  }

  // fires on page load because can't find element
  function obCallback(payload) {
    // console.log(payload[0].isIntersecting); // whether element is in view or not
    // console.log(payload[0].intersectionRatio); // how much of the element is showing
    if (payload[0].intersectionRatio === 1) {
      button.disabled = false;
      // stop observing the last element
      ob.unobserve(terms.lastElementChild);
    }
  }

  // takes in callback parameter
  // will be called every time it needs to check if something is currently on the page
  // watcher (needs to be told what to watch
  const ob = new IntersectionObserver(obCallback, {
    root: terms,
    threshold: 1,
  });

  // call observe method on what we want to watch
  // ob.observe(watch);
  ob.observe(terms.lastElementChild);

}
scrollToAccept();

$('.yes').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('.TOSHIDE').hasClass('fade-in-image')) {
        $('.TOSHIDE').toggleClass('fade-in-image').toggleClass('fade-out');
      }
      else if ($('.TOSHIDE').hasClass('fade-out')) {
        $('.TOSHIDE').toggleClass('fade-out').toggleClass('fade-in-image');
      } else {
        $('.TOSHIDE').toggleClass('fade-in-image');
      }
  });
```

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.wrapper-all {
  min-height: 94vh;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 80vh;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

button {
  background: #133C55;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

button[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.1;
  /* transform: translateX(-300%) scale(0.5); */
}

.terms-and-conditions {
  overflow: scroll;
}

footer {
  background-color: #192718;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

footer .container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

footer .container a {
  color: #fff;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #fce26a;
}

.tacbox {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 2em;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #eee;
  max-width: 800px;
}

input {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.TOSHIDE {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-in-image {
  animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn 5s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fade-out {
  animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Terms of Service</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./scroll-to-accept.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    function unhideTOS() {
      document.getElementById("text").style.display = "";
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function unlockBTN() {
      document.getElementById("text").style.display = "";
    }
  </script>

  <div class="tacbox">
    <!-- The code for the checkbox + download if checked. -->
    I agree to these &zwnj;<a href="#tos" class="yes">Terms and Conditions.</a>
    <br>
    <a id="text" style="display:none" href="file.doc" Download>Download!</a>
  </div>

  <div class="TOSHIDE">
    <div class="wrapper-all">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="terms-and-conditions">
          <h1>Terms and Conditions</h1>
          <p>Disclaimer THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF MERCHANTABILITY OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. You are the Current Maintainer of the Software, and to permit recipients of the Licensed Product for any such warranty, support,
            indemnity or liability obligations to one or more recipients of Covered Code. However, You may do so in a commercial product offering.</p>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <button class="accept" disabled autocomplete="off" id="myCheck" onclick="unlockBTN()">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./scroll-to-accept.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

made the code for the toggle you probably don't need that. The main part is the fade-out animation:

```js
//toggle var
var fade_state = true;
//on btn click
function fade() {
  //get the button and div
  let div = document.getElementById("div");
  let btn = document.getElementById("fade");
  //if faded in or out
  if (fade_state == true) {
    //trigers animation
    div.style.animation = "fade-out 2s forwards";
    //sets the text
    btn.innerHTML = "fade-in";
    //sets fade_state
    fade_state = false;
  } else if (fade_state == false) {
    //trigers animation
    div.style.animation = "fade-in 2s forwards";
    //sets the text
    btn.innerHTML = "fade-out";
    //sets fade_state
    fade_state = true;
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 100%;
}


/*the fade animations*/

@keyframes fade-out {
  from {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>fade-in_fade-out</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <button id="fade" onclick="fade()">fade-out</button>
  <div class="main" id="div">some text</div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you're using jQuery, you can use the [fadeToggle](https://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) method. For your code just replace `$('.TOSHIDE').toggleClass('active');` in your JavaScript with `$('.TOSHIDE').fadeToggle();` and play a little with duration options.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific reason we're not just toggling a css class and using transitions? You can just toggle the class on the wrapping div and adjust anything else you like. I'm not sure I understand the need for all the scripting.

```
.fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn ease 10s;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
}
```